# PHPExcel protect chart from drag and drop, and cut

Tags: charts, phpexcel

I used PHPExcel to generate chart and i done it, also i have protected (read only) the file.
But now i want to avoid from dragging of chart and also the cut option should be disabled or user should not be able to cut the chart. For any help thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code protects all objects in workbook - including charts:

```
$workbook->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setObjects(true);
```

Tested on PHPExcel 1.8.0.

Comment: @Kowalski can you help me to solve the problem of unreadable content when i want to open the file it show confirmation message after clicking yes chart is removed. here is the main details of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669078/phpexcel-drawing-chart-cause-unreadable-content-and-chart-removed

Comment: @MobasherFasihy, I'll look into this but maybe on Monday. I really don't know if I find some time to check it on weekend. Is this urgent matter for you?

Comment: yeah I'm searching for this around 3 day but still no solution thanks.

Comment: @Kowalski If you have time kindly help me its very urgent. tnx.