# PHPExcel chart protection

Tags: charts, phpexcel

I used PHPExcel library to generate chart and the bellow statement to protect the chart, but except chart area all other cells of excel is protected. How i can protect the chart area from editing and dragging? Thanks for any help and suggestion.

```
$workbook->getSecurity()->setLockWindows(true);
$workbook->getSecurity()->setLockStructure(true);
$workbook->getSecurity()->setWorkbookPassword("asd");
$sheet->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
$sheet->getProtection()->setSort(true);
$sheet->getProtection()->setInsertRows(true);
$sheet->getProtection()->setInsertColumns(true);
$sheet->getProtection()->setFormatCells(true);
$sheet->getProtection()->setSelectUnlockedCells(false);
$sheet->getProtection()->setSelectLockedCells(true);
$sheet->getProtection()->setPassword("asd");
```

May be some syntax mistake is here, but in real no syntax problem is existed. The only thing i want to have now is to protect the chart area from editing and dragging.
In above code `setSelectLockedCells(true)` do the job but when i open the file and unprotect it if i click on OK button with no changes in protection, chart change its protection to what i want, so how can i do that with no need to go in unprotect menu and clicking OK button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPExcel protect chart from drag and drop, and cut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578608/phpexcel-protect-chart-from-drag-and-drop-and-cut)

Answer (score -1):

This option isn't available for charts in PHPExcel, only for cells within a worksheet

Comment: can we protect data labels, x-axis, y-axis labels, and chart title?

Comment: There are no protection options available for any element of a chart, only for data in cells

Comment: Downvoted because this option is available: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23650392/925196

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski I stand corrected, I guess I don't remember things I wrote 2 years ago as well as I should

Comment: @MarkBaker What is the reason of unreadable content, when i download and open the generated file is show confirmation message that indicate drawing chart is unreadable and when i click on Yes button to confirm for repair no chart shows.

Comment: @MobasherFasihy - probably a bug, but without any information to go on, I can't say any more than that

Comment: @MarkBaker here is details of my code blocks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669078/phpexcel-drawing-chart-cause-unreadable-content-and-chart-removed